# Query for props list with or without values

Tags: php, mysql, select, relational

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` on three relational tables like these ones:

```
table_materials
-> material_id
- material_name

table_props
-> prop_id
- prop_name

table_materials_props
- row_id
-> material_id
-> prop_id
- prop_value
```

On my page, I'd like to get a result like this one but i have some problem with the query:

```
material    prop A    prop B    prop C    prop D    prop E
wood        350       NULL      NULL      84        16
iron        NULL      17        NULL      NULL      201
copper      548       285       99        NULL      NULL
```

so the query should return something like:

```
material   prop_name     prop_value
wood       prop A        350
wood       prop B        NULL
wood       prop C        NULL
wood       prop D        84
wood       prop E        16
// and go on with others rows
```

i thought to use something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_materials AS m
INNER JOIN table_materials_props AS mp
ON m.material_id = mp.material_id
INNER JOIN table_materials_props AS p
ON mp.prop_id = p.prop_id
ORDER BY p.prop_name
```

the problem is the query doesn't return the `NULL` values, and I need the same `prop` order for all the `materials` regardless of prop values are `NULL or not`

I hope this example is clear!

Comment: do you have a fixed list of "props" in your linked table to just the 5, or was that just an example... If fixed, would your intent that the number of "props" would be tightly controlled, and thus limited to create your cross-tab style results?

Comment: the number of props could increase, so I've decided to use this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-join (or inner join w/o a condition) all the options, then left join those to the associative entity table.  The left join will preserve prop/materials even when the combinations don't exist in the associative table.

Untested:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_materials AS m
INNER JOIN table_props as p 
LEFT JOIN table_material_props AS mp 
ON p.prop_id = mp.prop_id 
AND 
m.material_id = mp.material_id;
ORDER BY p.prop_name
```